# Unable install Android APK from ADB on Xaomi Redmi Note 4

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am using Redmi Note 4 and trying to install Apk through Android Studio and getting the error while launching the app

```
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs
```

I have already given all the necessary permissions like install via USB.

Comment: have u got any solution?

Comment: Yeah. Anjal's answer helped me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's Because of the *instant run*.

In case you are running a device with MIUI, 
`Developer Option` **>** `Turn on MIUI optimization` and turn it **off**.

**Reboot** your device and recompile the code.Instant Run will work again!!!

Comment: You save my day!!

Answer (score 4):

In case you are running a device with MIUI, you need to do:

1. Additional Settings ->  Developer Options -> Turn on MIUI optimization - Disable this option.
2. Also, Additional Settings -> Developer Options -> Install via USB: Enable this option

Reboot your device and recompile the code.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same problem in Redmi note 3. It was solved by disable instant run in android studio

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred mainly on *Android studio version 2.3 or higher*, due to **Instant Run** functionality of these version.

**MIUI Optimization**  creates issues in case of *non-MIUI based apps* such as Google Apps & Apps from Google Playstore. So Its better to disable if you rely on such Apps.

**Reason :** Using instant run we push certain code and resource changes to our running app without building a new APK. So it conflicts to MIUI optimization also.

**=> For disable MIUI Optimization follow below instructions :**

1) Setting > Additional settings > Developer options.

2) At bottom, here is an option **Turn on MIUI optimization**.

3) Disable to MIUI optimization > Click Turn off & reboot.